# Find a line and modify it in a csv file given an input

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file with a list of workers and I wanna make an script for modify their work group given their ID's. Lines in CSV files are like this:

**Before**:

```
ID           TAG GROUP
niub16677500;B00;AB0
```

**After**:

```
ID           TAG GROUP
niub16677500;B00;BC0
```

How I can make this?
I'm working with `awk` and `sed` commands but I couldn't get anything at the moment.

Comment: Can you share, before and after update ? hard to understand where is the group in your csv.

Comment: When the csv file has more lines, what do you want to change? Only user `niub16677500` or all groups `AB0` ? Is the new group fixed or is it somehow related to the old group, the first letter of the TAG or the ID?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Is the first line of the input file **really** space-separated while the rest is `;`-separated? Make sure the sample input/output you provide is truly representative of your real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With `awk`:**

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' -v id="niub16677500" -v new_group="BC0" '{if($1==id)$3=new_group}1' input.csv
ID;TAG;GROUP
niub16677500;B00;BC0
```

Redirect the output to a file and note that the csv header should use the same field separator as the body.

**Explanations**:

- `-F';'` to have input field separator as `;`
- `-v OFS=';'` same for the output FS
- `-v id="niub16677500" -v new_group="BC0"` define the variables that you are going to use in the awk commands
- `'{if($1==id)$3=new_group}1'` when the first column is equal to the value contained in variable `id` the overwrite the 3rd field and print the line

**With `sed`:**

```
id="niub16677500"; new_group="BC0"; sed "/^$id/s/;[^;]*$/;$new_group/" input.csv 
ID;TAG;GROUP
niub16677500;B00;BC0
```

You can either do an inline change using `-i.bak` option, or redirect the output to a file.

**Explanations**:

- Store the values in 2 variables
- `/^$id/` when you reach a line that starts with the ID store in the variable id, run sed search and replace
- `s/;[^;]*$/;$new_group/` search and replace command that will replace the last field by the new value

Comment: I've been looking for a more accurate information but I can't find how I can work with first and second column either. So, if ((;[^;]*$)) is for the last column, how can I select the first and the second one? Thanks in advance, your answer was so professional and clear

Comment: @Yeste: First column: `^[^;]*;` replaced by `$new_group;` and second column `;[^;]*;` replaced by `;$new_group;`

Comment: @Yeste: If you have enjoyed my help, do not hesitate to upvote my post as well by pressing on the arrow. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sed can do it,

```
echo 'niub16677500;B00;AB0' | sed 's/\(^niub16677500;...;\)\(...\)$/\1BC0/'
```

will replace the AB0 group in your example with BC0, by matching the user name, semicolon, whatever 3 characters and another semicolon, and then matching the remaining 3 characters. Then as an output it repeats the first match with \1 and adds BC0.

You can use :

```
sed 's/\(^niub16677500;...;\)\(...\)$/\1BC0/' <old_file >new_file
```

to make a new_file with this change.

https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html is a great resource, you should take a look at it.